# Cannot open .zip file from browser in QGIS 3.6.3 in Windows 7?

Tags: qgis-3, browser

In QGIS 3.6 on Windows 7, I can not open the .zip file from Browser. But it can open  through *Layer--Add layer--Add vector layer.*
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you try to open the .shp part with the browser? Your image shows .dbf as selected.

Comment: The first image is I want to show that I have the total files(.dbf,.shp etc.) in my ZIP file.My problem is that I can not open the .zip file from  browser but can do it throuth Layer--Add layer--Add vector layer.

Comment: Why is this a problem? It seems you've figured out how to add the layer to your project.

Comment: eee..In fact ,I learned that it can open .zip file from Browser directly,so this is my question--Why I can not do it in my qgis?

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any requested clarifications.